# JAVA: How to update JsonObject to another JsonObject

Tags: java, json

I have the JSON file: "D://test.json" which follows the MongoDB format:

```
{
"key":"value"
}

{
"embedded": { "key2": "value2" }
}

{
"array" : ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

I want to update the JsonObject to another. 
eg. for a repalcement query:

```
{
"courses": {"Math", "Biology"}
}
```

to replace

```
{
"embedded": { "key2": "value2" }
}
```

the file should be changed to:

```
{
"key":"value"
}

{
"courses": {"Math", "Biology"}
}

{
"array" : ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

How could I do it without using methods in the MongoDB package??

Comment: Your file content is not a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your json format is not valid.
Then, I assume, your are using the `json.org` library, Why not you use this code block?

`test.put("course", {"Math", "Biology"});
test.remove("embedded");`